# ExoPlayer MemoryLeak issues - LeakCanary

Tags: android, memory-leaks, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, leakcanary

I found a Memory Leak in my splash screen

it is playing video from asset folder on splash screen with **ExoPlayer**.

**LeakCanary** where it appears those
[image]
[image]

**initialise player:**

```
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
                this,
                new DefaultTrackSelector(),
                new DefaultLoadControl()
        );
        videoView.setPlayer(player);
        DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(Uri.parse("assets:///video.mp4"));
        final AssetDataSource assetDataSource = new AssetDataSource(this);
        try {
            assetDataSource.open(dataSpec);
        } catch (AssetDataSource.AssetDataSourceException e) {
            Timber.e(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DataSource.Factory() {
            @Override
            public DataSource createDataSource() {
                return assetDataSource;
            }
        };
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(
                assetDataSource.getUri(),
                dataSourceFactory,
                new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
                null,
                null
        );
        player.setRepeatMode(Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL);
        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
```

xml:

```
  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:resize_mode="zoom"
            app:use_controller="false" />
```

can you see any problem ? where is leak ? where is leak ? :)

Comment: Anonymous classes (`new DataSource.Factory`) hold implicit reference to the outer class (here the activity). You should not have this problem - you need to correctly dispose all resources used by the player when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: @EugenPechanec okay Thanks.